# Alpine package conflict in Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, package, dockerfile, alpine-linux

So here's the deal, i'm currently working with Api-Platform docker-compose config.

I needed to add `wkhtmltopdf` to generate pdf (duh.) but the package i get from alpine `v3.9` repo has a bug that randomly causes segfault because of qt5.

That issue [should be fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72463?focusedCommentId=451342&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-451342https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72463?focusedCommentId=451342&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-451342) by `qt5-qtbase-dev=5.12.2-r0`, and the `edge` repo contains 5.12.3 which could to fit me pretty well.

This qt5 version needs `icu-libs=64.x-r0` to run, which is conveniently in edge repo also (`64.2`), but the build then fails with following output:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  icu-libs-62.1-r0:
    breaks: world[icu-libs=64.2-r0]
    satisfies: .api-phpexts-rundeps-0[so:libicui18n.so.62]
               .api-phpexts-rundeps-0[so:libicuio.so.62]
               .api-phpexts-rundeps-0[so:libicuuc.so.62]
```

The script that runs php extensions dependencies needs `icu-libs=62.1-r0`:

```sh
runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )";

apk add --no-cache --virtual .api-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps;
```

But i can't tell what's requiring that old icu-libs in here... any suggestions?

[Edit] Here's my Dockerfile as it is after my last attempt:
https://gist.github.com/tsadiq/47582ea7d2f8b572cd360d6a9c9329b0

Lines 54-56 were an attempt to upgrade the `icu-libs` package after it's been used to build php dependencies just above. I even tried with `--force-broken-world` option but that obviously didn't work ^^'

The only other diff with my previously working Dockerfile is that `=5.12.3-r0` on line 70, which is what i need to get working.

[2nd Edit] 
In the end i couldn't get it to work, and i was advised to get a full wkhtmltopdf binary from a docker using QT patched version. The problem was solved but the rendering was completely off, so i had to roll back to bugged version and remove every external call for css libs and inline all the css directly in the html source, which solved the issue that caused the aforementioned segfault.

That's not exactly a solution but it does the job for me now.

Comment: can you post your dockerfile

Comment: Sure @Adiii  sorry i didn't see your answer earlier, i only received an email 15mns ago... I edited my message with a Dockerfile gist.